# Using kendo UI draw vertical line chart

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I need to plot a chart that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YYLM.png). It lots data in vertical lines. I need to achieve this using Kendo UI for jQuery. I am new to Kendo UI

Following this [documentation](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/index) from Kendo UI website, I started doing it as below

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Capacity versus Depth",
                    font: "13px",
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom",
                    labels: {
                        font: "13px"
                    }
                },
                chartArea: {
                    background: ""
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "line",
                    style: "smooth"
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "Fixed Jc Capacity (Kips)",
                    data: [17.00, 27.00, 37.00, 47.00, 57.00, 67.00, 77.00, 87.00, 97.00, 107.00]
                }, {
                    name: "UF Total Capacity (Kips)",
                    data: [17.00, 27.00, 37.00, 47.00, 57.00, 67.00, 77.00, 87.00, 97.00, 107.00]
                }, {
                    name: "Minimum Tip Elevation",
                    data: [17.00, 27.00, 37.00, 47.00, 57.00, 67.00, 77.00, 87.00, 97.00, 107.00]
                }, {
                    name: "Nominal Bearing Resistance",
                    data: [17.00, 27.00, 37.00, 47.00, 57.00, 67.00, 77.00, 87.00, 97.00, 107.00]
                }, {
                    name: "UF Tip Capacity (Kips)",
                    data: [17.00, 27.00, 37.00, 47.00, 57.00, 67.00, 77.00, 87.00, 97.00, 107.00]
                }],
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        format: "{0}%",
                        font: "13px",
                        data: [17.00, 27.00, 37.00, 47.00, 57.00, 67.00, 77.00, 87.00, 97.00, 107.00]
                    },
                  
                        title: {
                            text: "Displacement (Feet)",
                            font: "13px"
                    },
                                        
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    axisCrossingValue: -10,
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: [0.00, 100.00, 200.00, 300.00, 400.00, 500.00, 600.00, 700.00, 800.00, 900.00, 1000.00],
                    majorGridLines: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: "Capacity (Kips)",
                        font: "13px"
                    },
                    labels: {
                        rotation: "auto",
                        font: "13px"
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "{0}%",
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                }
            });
```

It turned out to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RcGp.png), this shows data in horizontal lines, but I need it to match with my first image, which has data in vertical lines

Can someone help me on how to achieve the vertical line chart with Kendo UI?

Comment: Show your jQuery code.

Comment: Hi @quantumPuter thanks for responding, I have updated my question with more details as well as jquery code, can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding series type: verticalLine

```
 series: [
    { type: "verticalLine", data: [1, 2] }
  ]
```

See this [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/seriesdefaults.verticalline)